# Codeigniter Migration to Alter a Table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, migration, database-migration

I have crated a Migration in codeigniter to create a MySQL table with 4 columns. Now I want to change the name of one of the columns without losing the data in that table.

First, I have enabled migration & set the version to 1.
Then, I have created a `file 001_create_users.php` and added the following code.

```
class Migration_Create_users extends CI_Migration {

    public function up(){

        $this->dbforge->add_field(
            array(
                'id'        => array('type'=>'INT', 'constraint'=>11, 'unsigned'=>TRUE, 'auto_increment'=>TRUE),
                'email'     => array('type'=>'VARCHAR', 'constraint'=>100),
                'password'  => array('type'=>'VARCHAR', 'constraint'=>255),
                'created'      => array('type'=>"TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
            )
        );

        $this->dbforge->add_key('id');
        $this->dbforge->create_table('users');

    }

    public function down(){

        $this->dbforge->drop_table('users');

    }
}
```

Now I want to change the column name '`date`' to '`created_at`'. So how should I do it? I mean what is the best way to do it? 
Also can anyone explain me how to do a rollback? Because I have used the folwing controller to run the migration.

```
class Migration extends Admin_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($version){

        $this->load->library('migration');

        if( !$this->migration->version($version)){
            show_error($this->migration->error_string());
        }
        echo "I'm in Migration";
    }

}
```

So, If I run http://localhost/migration/index/1 It will run the up() function. What should I do to perform a rollback via browser? Can I create another method and call it?

I still do not understand how the migration actually works, Can anyone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try browsing `http://localhost/migration/index/0` to go back to version 0. OR you can create separate function 'rollback' to rollback to a specific version and make index function to migrate up only using `$this->migration->current()`

Comment: If I go to http://localhost/migration/index/0 is it a roll back? Does that call the down() function in the 001_Migrations? or Can you explain me how to write the rollback?

Comment: Basically for rollback you need to use `$this->migration->version()` which you are already using. You can check you current version from migration table in your database. To go to any previous version is rollback. So, basically when you call `$this->migration->version(<version_num>)` CI checks db and decide whether rollback or migrate up. Hope this answers your question.